# How to use do-while loop to make Magic 8 Ball program in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am trying to create a Magic 8 Ball program that:

1. Stores all the responses in a String array using an initializer list.

   2. Generates a random number for the responses using a random object (in the range 0 to 19).
   3. Prompts the user to enter a question.
   4. Uses the random number to access and display the corresponding response.
   5. Asks the user if they want to ask another question (using a do-while loop). The code should repeat as long as the user says “yes”.

I am having trouble with step 5.

All the other steps I have been able to accomplish well, but when I input "yes", instead of it letting me ask another question it just skips that and gives me the answer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  //initializing variables
  int stop = 0;
  String otherQ,q;

  //initializing array
  String[] responses = {
  "It is certain.",
  "It is decidedly so.",
  "Without a doubt.",      
  "Yes - definitely.",
  "You may rely on it.",
  "As I see it, yes.",
  "Most likely.",
  "Outlook good.",
  "Yes.",      
  "Signs point to yes.",
  "Reply hazy, try again.",
  "Ask again later.",
  "Better not tell you now.",
  "Cannot predict now.",
  "Concentrate and ask again.",      
  "Don't count on it.",
  "My reply is no.",
  "My sources say no.",
  "Outlook not so good.",   
  "Very doubtful."};


  //creates objects
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  Random rn = new Random();

  //input
  //THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING A PROBLEM.
  do {
      System.out.print("What is your question? ");
      q = scan.nextLine(); 
      System.out.println(responses[rn.nextInt(19)]);  //method caller


  while (stop == 0) {

        System.out.print("Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): ");
        otherQ = scan.next(); 

        if (otherQ.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
          break;
        }else if (otherQ.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
           stop = 1;
        }

     }
  } while (stop == 0);
```

My expected result is:

```
    What is your question? Question goes here   
    As I see it, yes.  
    Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): yes  
    What is your question? Cannot predict now.    
    Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no):
```

The results I am getting with the code above:

```
    What is your question? Question goes here
    It is certain.
    Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): yes
    What is your question? Question goes here
    Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): no
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct implementation for this question would be as follows:

```
          //initializing variables
          int stop = 0;
          String otherQ,q;

          //initializing array
          String[] responses = {
          "It is certain.",
          "It is decidedly so.",
          "Without a doubt.",      
          "Yes - definitely.",
          "You may rely on it.",
          "As I see it, yes.",
          "Most likely.",
          "Outlook good.",
          "Yes.",      
          "Signs point to yes.",
          "Reply hazy, try again.",
          "Ask again later.",
          "Better not tell you now.",
          "Cannot predict now.",
          "Concentrate and ask again.",      
          "Don't count on it.",
          "My reply is no.",
          "My sources say no.",
          "Outlook not so good.",   
          "Very doubtful."};


          //creates objects
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
          Random rn = new Random();

          //input
          //THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING A PROBLEM.
          do {
              System.out.print("What is your question? ");
              q = scan.nextLine(); 
              System.out.println(responses[rn.nextInt(19)]);  //method caller

              System.out.print("Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): ");
              otherQ = scan.nextLine(); 

          } while (otherQ.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

You can drop the nested while loop in the do-while, remember a `do-while` loop only needs the one condition at the end of the `do` section.

Your logic was in the right direction, get the user's question, get the answer, then ask them if they want to ask another question.

Also, swap the `.next()` to a `.nextLine()` for getting the user's decision to continue.

I just made another small update at the bottom to avoid the confusing conditionals you added so that `yes = 1` and `no = 0`.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!

Comment: I have added a couple of `hasNextLine()` checks before calling the `Scanner.nextLine()` or else directly calling `Scanner.nextLine()` and not checking for the presence of next line will cause the program to throw the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` saying that there is no line found.   
Other than that the logic is good in this one.

Comment: This edit actually doesn't work.

First off, if you wrap the assignment of `otherQ` in the `if` statement to check whether or not the Scanner has a next input line, the `while` condition will have a compilation error cause `otherQ` is not defined now.

Also, as far as I know, we do not need `hasNextLine()` here? We are not reading input from a file or any other input, we are getting input from the console. If that is wrong, someone please let me know and we can fix the compilation error and include these checks.

Answer (score 2):

- You have two nested while loops. You only need one.
- use nextLine() - **this is your main bug**.
- I also switched your int to a boolean

Here is the code:

```java
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initializing variables
        boolean continueAsking = true;
        String otherQ;

        // initializing array
        String[] responses = { "It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.",
                "You may rely on it.", "As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.",
                "Signs point to yes.", "Reply hazy, try again.", "Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.",
                "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again.", "Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.",
                "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful." };

        // creates objects
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rn = new Random();

        // input
        do{
            System.out.print("What is your question? ");
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(responses[rn.nextInt(19)]); // method caller

            System.out.print("Would you like to ask another question? (Answer yes or no): ");
            otherQ = scan.nextLine();

            continueAsking = !otherQ.equalsIgnoreCase("no");

        } while (continueAsking);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to use a do-while loop, so when the person says that they wanna ask another question, it repeats "What is your question?" just like the expected result I gave you on my posted question.

Comment: Sure you can use do-while... I've updated the code. It doesn't change much. Do while guarantees at least one execution whereas while(...) would test the condition first.

Comment: Also, @DavidBrossard add next line presence checks before calling `Scanner.nextLine()` or else you'll end up with `NoSuchElementException`